# How is the similar of routes from browser-router to app-router from next?

Tags: next.js

this is my side bar functionality i cant put in the loyout beacuse it cause error

```
     {activeMenu ? (
          <div className='w-72 fixed sidebar dark:bg-secondary-b bg-white'>
            <Sidebar />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className='w-0 dark:bg-secondary-dark-bg'>
            <Sidebar />
          </div>
        )}
        {/* Main Screen Active Menu Functionality */}
        <div className={
          `dark:bg-main-bg bg-main-bg 
          min-h-screen w-full 
          ${activeMenu ? 'md:ml-72' : 'flex-2'}`
        }>
```

when i used in the page.tsx i t work correctly is more about the context loop so thats why i ahve to put it the page the thing is if i put this in the main frame doesnt work as it would with the lyout.tsx so i want to use similiar tools like browser router routes

i have my layout.tsx and my page.tsx im developing a dashboard  but not  in the lyout if not the pagetsx because to make the sidebar hide i have to do it in the page.tsx  in react if i need to show pages in the main frame i could use routes to show the pages but i next i dont very sure about what to use to show pages in the main frame

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.